# Doubling up of messages

Tags: android

I am working on an android chat application in which we store messages locally to avoid loading the messages again and again and just get the new messages from the server.

I am facing a problem with below scenario:

- Android app user sends a message to the server and lost internet connection before receiving the response from the server.
- This message remains in the queue on the mobile app end because queue gets cleared when a response returned from the server.
- When internet connection comes back, we can see the same message 2 times (one that was sent before internet connection on the mobile phone went off and 2nd is sent when internet connection comes back)

How can we get rid of this case? We can't clear the queue of messages until we get a response back from the server that messages are received/stored on the server.

Ideas?

Comment: share your code people try to find out solution?

Comment: @SushilKumar Sharing the code here won't really help because I am looking for a solution to handle this particular scenario.

Comment: People doesn't predict here. What you did and provide you solution of predicting solution.

Comment: Well, you need some reconcilation service that says which messages have/haven't been synced. When online, you should only show those that have synced.

Comment: Generally, you could use Firebase, Couchbase Lite, or RethinkDB to avoid re-implementing this feature

Comment: @cricket_007 I agree. The client is using MySQL server on the backend to save messages and PHP APIs return response after saving the messages. If this response gets missed because of immediate internet connection cut off then this issue of doubling up occurs.

Comment: A beginning solution would be to add some `lastSynced` or `lastUpdated` column to reduce what you are querying when you do perform a sync.

Comment: I thought of this earlier but this would work only when you are sure that last sync worked fine. We don't know here if sync was successful.
If we save `lastSynced` in the mobile app - it won't help until we are sure that messages are synced on the server
We can probably have `lasySynced` on both ends and then check mobile app's `lastSynced` with server's `lastSynced` and if it looks almost same then don't sync new messages to avoid doubling up? But this could also create problems for the new messages to be synced.

Answer (score 0):

Good day! I think, the server method you call must be idempotent. In simple term the second call for the same message (and third and so on) must do nothing. It's a common solution for such problems.